# CSS auto width div

Tags: css, google-maps

This is driving me nuts.

The situation is as follows.
I have 1 wrapper div that needs to span the entire width / height of the screen.
I need 1 div that is positioned on the right hand of the screen and has a fixed width (eg. 100px;).
Then the other div needs to span the remaining left half of the screen (no further !).

Note: I don't want to float the elements, I really need the divs to span the entire height of the screen, because a Google Map will be loaded into the div.
I am aware of the calc function in css, but I don't want to use it, because IE8 doesn't support it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gze4vcd2/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#wrapper{ 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: greenyellow;
}

#left{ 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    width: auto; 
    background: blue; 
}

#right{ 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 200px; 
    background: yellow; 
}
```

This doesn't work at all.
I have tried all sorts of things, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Looks like you want "absolute positioning"? Bad idea.

Comment: It's not like you have a choice with Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `position: fixed` for your `#Wrapper`

```css
#wrapper{ 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: greenyellow;
}

#left{ 
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    right: 100px;
}

#right{ 
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px
}
```

Above is the updated code that works for me

Comment: What I need is for the blue part to have the remaining width of the screen. This is very important, because the Google Map should not go below the right div. This will bring me in trouble...

Comment: Thanks for saving the day!